# python itertools groupby several attributes

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm trying to group objects by attributes. I know how to do for one but how to include several attributes, for example:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name1, name2, id_):
        self.name1 = name1
        self.name2 = name2
        self.id_= id_
 def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.id_}>{self.name1}-{self.name2}"

l = [Node('WWA', 'KATO', 1), Node('WWA', 'POZ', 2), Node('SZCZ', 'GDN', 3), Node('GDN', 'BYD', 4), Node('BIA', 'OLS', 5), Node('LUB', 'WWA',6 )]

get_attr = attrgetter("name1")
l= [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l, key=get_attr), get_attr )]
```

result:

```
[[<5>BIA-OLSZ],
 [<4>GDN-BYD],
 [<6>LUB-WWA],
 [<3>SZCZ-GDN],
 [<1>WWA-KATO, <2>WWA-POZ]]
```

I'd like to group by name1 or by name2 and get it this:

```
[[<5>BIA-OLSZ],
 [<4>GDN-BYD],<3>SZCZ-GDN],
 [<1>WWA-KATO, <2>WWA-POZ, <6>LUB-WWA]]
```

Comment: How would you have grouped <6>LUB-WMA if there was another node with a LUB attribute ?  Would you duplicate it in both a 'WMA' and a 'LUB' group or would there be a precedence on the first attribute, or something else ?

Comment: This is the result I want to get: [[<5>BIA-OLSZ],  [<4>GDN-BYD],  [<3>SZCZ-GDN],  [<1>WWA-KATO, <2>WWA-POZ], <6>LUB-WWA]]
I want objects that have name1-name1, name2-name2 or name1-name2 in common

Comment: That was already clear, my question is where would you place <7>LUB-GDN if it was in the list ?  Would it be grouped with <1>,<2> and <6> or with <4> or would it cause <6> to go in a different group with <7>?

Comment: Also, did you mean for <6>LUB-WWA to be inside the previous sublist or is it your aim really to have it not be in a sub list at all ?  Your expected result: `[<1>WWA-KATO, <2>WWA-POZ], <6>LUB-WWA]` contradicts your requirement. Did you mean it to be `[<1>WWA-KATO, <2>WWA-POZ, <6>LUB-WWA]]` ?

Comment: sorry for my mistake, it should be like this: [[<5>BIA-OLSZ],
 [<4>GDN-BYD],<3>SZCZ-GDN],
 [<1>WWA-KATO, <2>WWA-POZ, <6>LUB-WWA]]

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able do that using groupby because you'll need to have two identifiers for each group.

To have multiple keys for each group, you can use a dictionary where the list of nodes is associated to two keys (name1 and name2).  Adding each node to the group corresponding to one of its names will produce a (redundant) list of groups as the dictionary's values().  You can then get the distinct (non-empty) groups out of those:

```
d = dict()
for n in l:
    d.setdefault(n.name1, d.setdefault(n.name2,[])).append(n) # link both names
l = [*{id(g):g for g in d.values() if g}.values()]            # distinct groups

print(l)

[[<1>WWA-KATO, <2>WWA-POZ, <6>LUB-WWA], 
 [<3>SZCZ-GDN, <4>GDN-BYD], 
 [<5>BIA-OLS]]
```

Note that this doesn't formally address my original question about overlapping group attributes, so if we add Node('LUB','GDN',7) to the list, it will end up in one of the groups which may or may not be where you want it to be:

```
l = [Node('WWA', 'KATO', 1), Node('WWA', 'POZ', 2), Node('SZCZ', 'GDN', 3), 
     Node('GDN', 'BYD', 4), Node('BIA', 'OLS', 5), Node('LUB', 'WWA',6 ), 
     Node('LUB', 'GDN',7 )]

d = dict()
for n in l:
    d.setdefault(n.name1, d.setdefault(n.name2,[])).append(n) 
l = [*{id(g):g for g in d.values() if g}.values()]            

print(l)

[[<1>WWA-KATO, <2>WWA-POZ, <6>LUB-WWA, <7>LUB-GDN], 
 [<3>SZCZ-GDN, <4>GDN-BYD], 
 [<5>BIA-OLS]]
```

This can be addressed by selecting the attribute with the largest number of nodes as the grouping key.  The Counter class (from collections) can help with determining the attribute frequencies.

```
from collections import Counter
f = Counter(n.name1 for n in l) + Counter(n.name2 for n in l) # frequencies
d = dict()
for n in l:
    k = (n.name1,n.name2)[(f[n.name2],n.name2)>(f[n.name1],n.name1)]
    d.setdefault(k,[]).append(n)  # group with most frequent attrib.
l = list(d.values())

print(l)
[[<1>WWA-KATO, <2>WWA-POZ, <6>LUB-WWA],
 [<3>SZCZ-GDN, <4>GDN-BYD, <7>LUB-GDN],
 [<5>BIA-OLS]]
```

*Note that I also use the attributes themselves in the frequency comparison so that the tie-breaker is applied consistently (based on larger name)*

Comment: Thank you very much, very clever solutions. I will use the second approach. Btw, I found out that you can use something like this: (x, y) [True \ False].
Can you tell me how this line of code works (I know setdefault returns a value for a key or inserts a key with a value defalut): d.setdefault (n.name1, d.setdefault (n.name2, [])). Append ( n) -> (in one iteration) {"KATO: <1> WWA-KATO, "WWA": <1> WWA-KATO}
And what's going on here (it's magic :)): [* {id (g): g for g in d.values () if g} .values ()].

Comment: From an empty dictionary, the inner setdefault creates a key:list pair for name2 and that list becomes the default for name1 ending up with both keys referencing the same list.  Later on any node that has either of these keys are their name1/name2 will append to the existing list because, if the other node's name2 is the same, it will use the list as default for name1 and if name1 is the same then the default will be ignored and the existing list will be used.

Comment: The `id()` function returns an internal identifyer for an object (e.g. a list).  by using it as the key in a dictionary comprehension, each list of the original dictionary (d.values()) will only be kept once in the temporary dictionary of id:list.  Then the final list of groups is formed by getting the values() of the temporary id:list dictionary.